# My BCP command keeps asking for credentials whether I provide them or not

Tags: sql-server, syntax, bcp

I run this SQL code:

```
declare @sqlselect varchar(100), @cmd varchar(100)
set @sqlselect = '"select * from [sr05107].[armaninodw].[dbo].[vw_items]"'
set @cmd = 'bcp '+ @sqlselect + ' queryout "D:\PrecisionPoint\Customer_Credit_Limit_rpt.csv" -T'
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd
```

I get this error:

> User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name or use -T for Trusted Connection

Please help!

Tried adding `-U` and `-P` while removing the `-T`.

Comment: You're using SQL Server to shell out to the operating system to run a query inside SQL Server to then output the data into a flat file in the operating system. What this does is it will run xp_cmdshell as the service account SQL Server is running as, which you can verify by running `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami';`. This will show a domain account or, more likely in your case, `nt authority\system` which will essentially try to run as an anonymous user. Why not call BCP from PowerShell or CMD so it will run as you instead, and skip at least one layer in that process?

Comment: ...and you won't be able to pass _Windows_ credentials using `-U` and `-P`. Only SQL Auth credentials.

Comment: If you want to use `bcp.exe` why don't you just call it from an actual command line? Why abuse TSQL for this?

Answer (score 2):

`@cmd varchar(100)` will be too short to hold full command line, try `@cmd varchar(4000)`.

As usual, it's good to PRINT your dynamic strings.

Comment: Good eye. But even if they fix that, they still might run across the blocker I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, maybe this should've been a comment instead of an answer. He also seem to be using a 4 part name which can complicate the whole permission chain thing

Comment: Again, good eyes! That is also a problem. And even _more_ reason why this shouldn't be launched from inside SQL Server in the first place.

Comment: One could run the servers on AD accounts, this simplifies some of these integration issues but yeah, agree in general. Maybe the main problem is that Microsoft never implemented a proper native export which would probably cut down number of questions here in half